# MS GraphAPI - Report.Read.All on Postman

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to use Postman to access GraphAPI. I have created an app on AzureAD and granted report.read.all in the Application permissions. I've consented the permissions as well.

I then created a Client Secret and added all the variables in Postman, however when running a query

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getTeamsDeviceUsageUserDetail(period='D7')
```

I get :

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "UnknownError",
        "message": "{\"error\":{\"code\":\"S2SUnauthorized\",\"message\":\"Invalid permission.\"}}",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2022-08-29T07:42:52",
            "request-id": "986de9b4-6146-40f9-9bc3-",
            "client-request-id": "986de9b4-6146-40f9-9bc3-"
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Is there any info that I still need to configure for this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time.... just, Time...
After waiting 30 minutes and refreshing the token, it worked

I wonder if the User.Read.All permission is required.